# What are the odds of the last three digits of my post number being the same, with a crazy variable?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm really new to this stack so I appreciate any tips on how to better phrase my question.

There's a website called 4chan.org, an imageboard that has up to 22 million monthly visitors across 71 different boards.

On a certain board, I made a post with the post number 185,638,777. In the same thread, I added another post with the post number 185,639,111

Crazy variable: 
I ended up replying to my own post (see attached image). I don't how to quantify the probability of that, or even put it into words, but if anyone can solve it be my guest.

[Here is the post in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1PjZ.png)

The questions I have are:

1. What are the odds of the last 3 digits of my post number being the same
2. What are the odds of the last 3 digits of my post being the same, and me replying to the first post?

Comment: With 22 million monthly visitors, there are bound to be frequent occurrences of coincidences a lot more "remarkable" than what you described here. You just happened to be the one who made the posts this time.

Answer (score 2):

The probability is $\frac{10}{1000}=\frac1{100}$ For another one to also have the last three digits the same, you square the probability: $(\frac1{100})^2=\frac1{10000}$

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's the most conservative answer, there are actually a lot more variables that come into play but I'm too intoxicated to describe them in words right now.
+1 would rep if I could

Comment: 1 in 10000 chance

Comment: This calculation assumes that there are enough posts that the trailing digits are independent.  This is not all that good an assumption because the two posts were only $334$ posts apart.  The posts that meet the requirement are generally $111$ posts apart, except that ones that end $999$ are followed immediately by $000$.  The average is one in $100$.  This is a general problem when calculating probabilities of events in the real world-it is *very* hard to understand the probability distribution the events were drawn from.  Good answer.